# Python Pandas df is not defined

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with a script I wrote a while back, couple of months ago it worked fine without problem. However since then the OS has been updated.
The script works fine until it tries to create a dataframe with pandas

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dir_input = '/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/Script/input/'
osdir = []
alldir = []
for all_files in os.listdir(dir_input):
    alldir.append(all_files)
for file in os.listdir(dir_input): #Adds all the specified files to the list osdir
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
    osdir.append(file)
    print("Found {0}".format(file))

for filename in osdir:
    (fileroot, extension) = os.path.splitext(filename)
    print 'Processing file...'
    print fileroot
    print ''
    # pandas works with so called dataframes to import the data. Since I dont need all the columns we only use column d,f and j
    df = pd.read_excel(dir_input+filename,parse_cols="D,F,J", index=df.index)
...
```

The error I get using spyder

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-2cf9c86bcb8c>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('/home/xxx/python_scripts/xpos-frame-mean_batch_v1.1.py', wdir='/home/cdoering/python_scripts')

  File "/home/xxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 682, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/xxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 78, in execfile
builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/home/xxx/python_scripts/script.py", line 54, in <module>
df = pd.read_excel(dir_input+filename,parse_cols="D,F,J", index=df.index)

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

My feeling is there is something wrong with pandas, maybe? I uninstalled it using conda and reinstalled it. Tried uninstalling with pip, but never used pip to install it so it couldn't find it. I am at a loss.

Comment: I don't see how this worked before, `df` isn't actually defined anywhere as far as I can see before the first time it is used.

Comment: You're referencing the index prior to creation in this line `df = pd.read_excel(dir_input+filename,parse_cols="D,F,J", index=df.index)`, why is this necessary?

Comment: Not sure why you think this is anything to do with Pandas. `df` is in your code, and it's not defined before the line you use it on.

Comment: You are right EdChum, I removed the index=df.index and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@EdChum said in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045291/python-pandas-df-is-not-defined#comment55845086_34045291), the problem is 'referencing the index prior to creation'. Specifically, when you have `index=df.index` you are referring to the `index` attribute of the `df`, but you haven't created the `df` yet, so that attribute doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I removed the index=df.index and that worked well. I have no idea how that worked before :)

Comment: Possibly you had a previously defined `df` in your session somewhere?

Comment: no, not to my knowledge. This is the full script beginning. There is nothing I left out before the first df appears. Maybe from another script? I have no idea :)